# How to adjust the volume of 2 AVPlayers independently?

Tags: ios, avplayer

I'm working on an app that plays two different tracks from the users iPod library.
I need to be able to adjust the volume of the two tracks independently.
Looking around online I found a suggestion to adjust the AVMutableAudioMix on the playerItems that are active in each of the two AVPlayers.

I've subclassed AVPlayer to include some functionality that I need to emulate a musicPlayer like the iPod.
Below is the method inside my AVPlayer subclass that I would like to use to adjust that players playerItem volume.
This method is being called by my viewController when a sliderValue is changed.

My result is that the volume does not change.
Does anyone know if this approach can work?
It seems to me that if it doesn't my only choice is to dig into Core Audio.

Thanks.

```
-(void)setPlayerItemVolume:(float)itemVolume
{
        self.volume = itemVolume;

        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];

        AVPlayerItem *currentPlayerItem = [self currentItem];

        CMTime currentTime = [currentPlayerItem currentTime];

        [audioInputParams setVolume:itemVolume atTime:currentTime];

        //[audioInputParams setTrackID:[currentPlayerItem trackID]];

        //[allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];

        NSArray *allAudioParams = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:audioInputParams, nil];


        AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];

        [audioMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

        [currentPlayerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS 7 introduces 2 new properties on AVPlayer: 'volume' and 'muted'. You should be able to use those to independently change audio levels.